# How do I check if file upload time recorded on UI is correct in cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I am writing cypress test case in which I have to upload a file. Once upload completes, the UI refreshes to show the upload time. I have to assert that the file upload time recorded is indeed correct. So I captured the date time displayed. It was `Oct. 5, 2021, 3:29 a.m.`. Also once upload completes I can get the current time in the test case with say `new Date()`. My doubt is how do I compare these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date-time captured from the UI is a string, so you need to parse it to a date for comparison.

For example, using [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format)

Since the string is a slightly non-standard format, you can supply a format string for parsing.

The only thing that needs extra work is removing the dots in `a.m.`

```js
const dateString = 'Oct. 5, 2021, 12:31 a.m.'
  .replace('a.m.', 'am')
  .replace('p.m.', 'pm')

const uploadDate = dayjs(dateString, 'MMM. DD, YYYY, HH:MM a')  // parse

const now = dayjs()
expect(uploadDate.isSame(now, 'minute')).to.eq(true) // uploaded in last minute

// or

const diffMinutes = now.minute() - uploadDate.minute()
expect(diffMinutes).to.be.lte(1)
```